# How do I hide var_dump output?

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to map my data in FTP but cannot hide the output of `var_dump`.
My goal is to do get the output but as a notification in my mail box.
Getting it in my mail box is not an issue. But the issue is I am unable to hide the output.
As well as getting the output as an hyperlink.
So I want to hide but make it as an hyperlink message in my mail box.

For example:

```
///////Mapping///////////////////////////////////////////
$host=$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$rootpath = '.';
$fileinfos = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($rootpath));
foreach($fileinfos as $pathname => $fileinfo) {
    if (!$fileinfo->isFile()) continue;
    var_dump('http://www.'.$host.(substr_replace($pathname,"/",0,2).'<br>'));
}
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Three options:

1. Use output buffering:

   ob_start();
   var_dump('http://www.'.$host.(substr_replace($pathname,"/",0,2).'
   '));
   $output = ob_get_clean();
2. Use [`print_r()`](http://www.php.net/print_r). You lose the data types but the values are still there:

   $output = print_r('http://www.'.$host.(substr_replace($pathname,"/",0,2).'
   '), true);
3. Use [`var_export()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php) (Please upvote [@SimonBlok](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22017365/250259) for pointing this out)

   $output = var_export('http://www.'.$host.(substr_replace($pathname,"/",0,2).'
   '));

Answer (score 1):

Put it in HTML comments, then check your source.

And on a different note... var_dump is not intended to be used that way. It's to dump a variable that already exists, not for a variable that still has to be instantiated...

```
///////Mapping///////////////////////////////////////////
$host=$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$rootpath = '.';
$fileinfos = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($rootpath));
foreach($fileinfos as $pathname => $fileinfo) {
    if (!$fileinfo->isFile()) continue;
    echo '<!---';
    var_dump('http://www.'.$host.(substr_replace($pathname,"/",0,2).'\n'));
    echo '--->';
}
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [var_export](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php) to catch the output of the var_dump and store it in a variable for later usage.

Comment: Somehow that function has eluded me. Nice catch.