# how to echo multidimensional array in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

i am trying to print multidimensional array in php below is my array and array variable is gplus

```
 Array ( [0] => Array ( [name] => krishna sitaram [email] => kasyapa25@gmail.com ) 
            [1] => Array ( [name] => ravi kumar [email] => ravikumar@gmail.com )
```

i tried bellow

```
foreach($gplus as $gvalue){
      echo  $gvalue."<br />";
      }
```

but not working.

the result should be

```
name               email
krishna sitaram   kasyapa25@gmail.com  
ravi kumar        ravikumar@gmail.com
```

Thank you all i got the the correct solution is

```
foreach($gplus as $array){
     echo $array['name']."<br />";
     echo $array['email']."<br />";

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're just debugging:

```
print_r($your_associative_array);
```

If you want to print it:

```
foreach($gplus as $array){
    foreach($array as $key=>$value){
      echo "Key: $key / Value: $value<br />";
    }
}
```

Comment: i did a small change foreach($gplus as $array){
  echo $array['name']."<br />";
  echo $array['email']."<br />";
   
}

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($gplus as $k => $gvalue) {
    echo $gvalue["name"]." ".$gvalue["email"]."<br />";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know a little late but you can do also this, if you like to use the var_dump function for debug information:

```
ob_start();
var_dump($array);
$array_content_string = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

you can use this $array_content_string as normal string

Comment: This advice is also provided at [this earlier, more comprehensive answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22017051/2943403).

Answer (score -1):

first your might know that you have a assoc array not a simple array , to display your assoc array you have to write :

```
foreach ( $arrayRow as $key => $value)
{
      echo $value;
}
```